# Guarantees of traversal order in AWS Neptune graph database

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I'm working with Gremlin and AWS Neptune graph database.

I was wondering if any query, when it is applied in different times (but the query stays exactly the same), could potentially result in different traversal order and therefore maybe return the same items in a different order.
I know that Gremlin doesn't guarantee any such order but I couldn't find anything regarding the matter on AWS documentation.
I know that to guarantee some order I could always use order() but it is obviously less efficient.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As with most other databases the order of data returned by Amazon Neptune is not guaranteed unless you explicitly order the results.